# Does this complex remain exact after I restrict the maps?

Tags: matrices, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

$R$ is a commutative ring with unity. Assume you have two matrices $A:R^n\rightarrow R^m$ and $B:R^m\rightarrow R^n$ such that they form an exact complex in the obvious way, i.e., $$\cdots\rightarrow R^n\stackrel{A}\rightarrow R^m\stackrel{B}\rightarrow R^n\rightarrow\cdots.$$ Call $S$ the subring of $R$ generated by the entries of $A$ and $B$ (I mean $S=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[a_{ij},b_{ij}]$, where $n$ is the characteristic of $R$), and restrict the matrices to the ring $S$. The restricted maps still form a complex. Is it exact? I'm pretty sure it is not, but I cannot find any counterexample. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Take $R=\mathbb Q[X,Y]$, $n=1$, $m=2$, $A=(-Y\ X^4)^T$ (here $^T$ stands for the transpose) and $B=(X^5\ XY)$. Then $S=\mathbb Z[X^5,X^4,XY,Y]$. Obviously $(-XY\ X^5)^T\in\ker B'$ and $(-XY\ X^5)^T\notin\operatorname{Im} A'$, where by $'$ we denoted the restrictions.

Comment: is there any particular reason for choosing this complex? It seems also to me that if you replace $x^4$ with $x^2$ and $x^5$ with $x^3$ it works anyway, am I right?

Comment: Actually what you have here it is not a complex because $AB$ is not zero, maybe when I asked the question it wasn't clear, but I meant the complex should be $\cdots\rightarrow R^m\rightarrow R^n\rightarrow R^m\rightarrow R^n\rightarrow\cdots$.

Comment: Dear @Chris, there is no particular reason for that choice. But what prove more about the phenomenon by considering an infinite complex instead of an exact sequence? (Unless this is a homework, and then I have to work more. ;)) Meanwhile I suggest you to edit your question by replacing "in the obvious way" with exactly what you want to say.

Comment: In the exercise that I had, I had to prove that in this case $n=m$, with the assumption of noetherianity. And I solved the exercise, I was curious to know if it was true in the non-noetherian case, my idea was to restrict to that noetherian subring, but I think you lose exactness.

Comment: $+1^{\infty}$ :-)

Comment: Dear @Chris, if I understand well in your exercise you assume that $R$ is Noetherian and have to prove that such an exact complex there exists only if $m=n$. So your next question is whether the conclusion holds true without noetherianity. Right?

Comment: yeah, I was curious about that, if by restricting the complex it remains exact I'm done, but I don't think it remains exact but I couldn't find any counterexample.